# Online judge moodle plugin

Tags: plugins, moodle

I want to create a course in moodle and hold contensts (like ACM contest).
Does moodle have a plugin to connect to domjudge?
Or does it have an online judge plugin?

Comment: Were you able to use the plugin mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/trampgeek/CodeRunner (disclaimer: I have never used Moodle nor this plugin).

Comment: Thanks but I want some plugin that runs Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Moodle Online Judge](https://github.com/hit-moodle/moodle-local_onlinejudge) plugin that judges, executes, and sandboxes C/C++ programs. It can also post data to [Sphere Engine](https://sphere-engine.com/) (If you have a valid access credentials to it).